# Sending an automated email through a nightly job

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-mail

I had the following SQL query:

```
select substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4) as 'Postcode'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 1 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'New Connections'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 2 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Domestic Metered'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 3 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Commercial Metered Low'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 4 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Commerical Metered High'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 5 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Domestic Keypad'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 6 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Generator'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 7 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Commercial Keypad'
from AccountExtensionBase as a
INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase as b ON a.AccountId = b.ParentId
where New_AccountStage = 7
and AddressTypeCode = 1
and substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2) = 'BT'
group by substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2),substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4)
order by substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2),substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4)
```

I now am trying to set this up as a nightly job to run and email myself the results but have had problems when trying to convert this to an automated stored procedure:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'support',
@recipients = 'test@mail.co.uk',
@subject = 'Post Code Analysis',
@query = N'select substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4) as ''Postcode''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 1 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''New Connections''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 2 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Domestic Metered''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 3 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Commercial Metered Low''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 4 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Commerical Metered High''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 5 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Domestic Keypad''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 6 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Generator''
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 7 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as ''Commercial Keypad''
from AccountExtensionBase as a
JOIN CustomerAddressBase as b ON a.AccountId = b.ParentId
where New_AccountStage = 7
and AddressTypeCode = 1
and substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2) = ''BT''
group by substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2),substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4)
order by substring(PostOfficeBox,1,2),substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4);',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'pca-test.txt'
```

When I run this query it is saying 'AccountExtensionBase' is not a valid object but it is contained within the TestCRM database that my SSMS is set to. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: how about when you use `use db_name; select substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4)…` or you can use `db_name.schema_name.object_name` ? Also, refer to [avoiding the schema prefix - is not a good practice](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query will be executed by `sp_send_dbmail` asynchronously, on a separate session that has `msdb` as current database. So you must use three-part names in your query:

```
@query = N'select substring(PostOfficeBox,1,4) as [Postcode]
...
from TestCRM.dbo.AccountExtensionBase as a
JOIN TestCRM.dbo.CustomerAddressBase as b ON a.AccountId = b.ParentId
...'
```